# Sass with CSS Modules & Webpack

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, webpack, css-modules

I've been building a project for a while using Webpack, Sass, and CSS modules. Normally in my `.scss` files, I define a class like:

```
:local(.button) {
    color: white;
}
```

and in my React components, in the `render` method, I require the styles:

```
render = () => {
    const styles = require('./MyStyles.scss');
    <div className={ styles.button } />
}
```

and all is good with the world. Everything works as expected.

Now today I was reading through the [CSS Modules page](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules) and noticed that none of the selectors were encompassed by `:local()` like mine and furthermore that they were importing the styles like:

```
import styles from './MyStyles.scss';
```

And I thought "Wow that looks much nicer, it's easier to see where it's imported, ect. And I'd love not to use `:local()` and just have things local by default." So I tried that and immediately ran into several problems.

1) `import styles from './MyStyles.scss';

Because I'm using ESLint on my React files, I immediately get an error thrown that `MyStyles.scss` doesn't have a default export which would normally make sense but the CSS Modules page stated:

> When importing the CSS Module from a JS Module, it exports an object with all mappings from local names to global names.

so I naturally expected the default export of the stylesheet to be the object they're referring too.

2) I tried `import { button } from './MyStyles.scss';`

This passes linting but `button` logs as undefined.

3) If I revert to the `require` method of importing my styles, anything not specified with `:local` is undefined.

For reference, my webpack loader (I'm also including [Node-Neat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-neat) and [Node-Bourbon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-bourbon), two awesome libraries):

```
{ test: /.(scss|css)$/, loader: 'style!css?sourceMap&localIdentName=[local]___[hash:base64:5]!resolve-url!sass?outputStyle=expanded&sourceMap&includePaths[]=' + encodeURIComponent(require('node-bourbon').includePaths) +
'&includePaths[]=' + encodeURIComponent(require('node-neat').includePaths[1]) + '&includePaths[]=' + path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'src/client/') }
```

My questions, following all of this, are:

1) When using CSS Modules with Sass, am I confined to using either `:local` or `:global`?

2) Since I'm using webpack, does that also mean I can only `require` my styles?

Comment: I would escape the wildcard (`.`) character in your loader's `test` property, like so: `test: /\.(scss|css)$/`

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Soon after posting, I figured out the solution. The problem, which I thought was quite confusing, was in my Webpack config. Originally my loader looked like:

```
loader: 'style!css?sourceMap&localIdentName=[local]___[hash:base64:5]!resolve-url!sass?outputStyle=expanded&sourceMap
```

which enabled to me to 1) `require` my Sass and 2) wrap my styles in `:local`.

However, the css loader was missing the `modules` option so that it looked like:

```
loader: 'style!css?modules&sourceMap&localIdentName=[local]___[hash:base64:5]!resolve-url!sass?outputStyle=expanded&sourceMap
```

Now I can `import` my styles and I don't have to wrap them in `:local` (although I presume I still can if I want to).

What I found most interesting about all this is that without the `modules` option, one can still use CSS Modules-esque features, although somewhat limiting.

EDIT:

Something I noticed, a future warning to whomever looks at this answer, is if you're using the [eslint-plugin-import](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-import) to lint the imports in your javascript code, it will throw an error upon importing styles like:

```
import styles from './MyStyles.scss';
```

because of the way CSS Modules exports the resulting styles object. That does mean you'll be required to do `require('./MyStyles.scss')` to bypass any warnings or errors.

Comment: When using eslint-plugin-import, you can ignore your scss files specifically. see: https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-import#importignore